# How to assert two collection that contains same data

Tags: c#, .net, assertion

I want to assert a resultant `List` with my expected `List`. My expected list looks like below code

```
List<GroupOfStuff> expectedResult = new List<GroupOfStuff>();
List<Stuff> stuffList = new List<Stuff>();
Stuff stuff = new Stuff
{
    DeliveryDays = 3
};
stuffList.Add(stuff);
GroupOfStuff groupByCountry = new GroupOfStuff
{
    Country = "Australia",
    StuffDetails = stuffList // List<Stuff> type
};
expectedResult.Add(groupByCountry);
```

And I have the actual as `List<GroupOfStuff> actual = obj.Result ()`

I went through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171411/how-to-assert-that-two-list-contains-elements-with-the-same-public-properties-in). But I got another `GroupOfStuff` class contains another `List` member. So, shell I go for separate assertion of each member of `GroupOfStuff` class or what is the suggestion, how shell I assert them.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is for unit testing? Then you can use this CollectionAssert.AreEqual in the namespace of microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.aspx )

Which you can find in Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll since .net 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the extension method `Enumerable.SequenceEqual<TSource>()` for that purpose. Small example how to use it:

```
        class Pet
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
        }

        public static void SequenceEqualEx1()
        {
            Pet pet1 = new Pet { Name = "Turbo", Age = 2 };
            Pet pet2 = new Pet { Name = "Peanut", Age = 8 };

            // Create two lists of pets.
            List<Pet> pets1 = new List<Pet> { pet1, pet2 };
            List<Pet> pets2 = new List<Pet> { pet1, pet2 };

            bool equal = pets1.SequenceEqual(pets2);

            Console.WriteLine(
                "The lists {0} equal.",
                equal ? "are" : "are not");
        }
```